# Select objects with unique ID's as another object type using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Using `LINQ`, I'm trying to select unique `Customer`'s as `Person` objects. I'm using `JSON` data in the following example but I'm working with `POCO` objects in `C#`. In this example, I chose `JSON` to keep things simple.

I have the following `Customer` list:

```
[
  {
     "id": 123,
     "name: "John Smith",
     "transactionDate": "2019-08-21T10:30",
     "amount": 8.50
  },
  {
     "id": 234,
     "name: "Jane Doe",
     "transactionDate": "2019-08-22T18:21",
     "amount": 75.00
  },
  {
     "id": 123,
     "name: "John Smith",
     "transactionDate": "2019-08-26T10:30",
     "amount": 10.00
  }
]
```

I want to get the unique customers as `Person` objects and the result, should look like this:

```
[
  {
     "id": 123,
     "name": "John Smith"
  },
  {
     "id": 234,
     "name": "Jane Doe"
  }
]
```

The following should give me the unique ID's.

```
var uniqueIds = customers.Select(x => x.id).Distinct();
```

How do I now extract unique `Person`'s from `List<Customer>()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Comment: What if you have two objects with id 123, one named "John Smith", the other "Smith, John"?

Comment: Please avoid editing the question with a solution. Instead, add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested answer or the other SO post didn't return the results I needed. Here's the code that worked.

```
var uniquePersons = customers
                        .Select(x => new Person() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
                        .GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Select(x => x.First())
                        .ToList();
```

I'm not saying this is the best way but this is what gave me a unique list of `Person` from a list of `Customer`.

I'd love to hear suggestions or explanations whether this is the best way to handle it or why the suggested answer didn't produce a `List<Person>()` with unique persons.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `GroupBy`:

```
var uniquePersons = customers
    .GroupBy(c => new Person() {Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name})
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Comment: @aloisdg I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate, but yes, the answers to the question you suggested can probably help the OP to solve their problem.

Comment: This got me close but didn't work. I updated the original post that shows what worked.